# How can I render multiple text inputs with a for loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to display 5 input fields on the screen within a for loop. I also want to apply a dynamic class to each of them later (according to their state). Here is my code:

```
function App() {
    ...

    return (
        <Grid container className={classes.root}>
            <CssBaseline />
            <Grid item xs={false} md={7} className={classes.image} />
            <Grid item xs={12} md={5} component={Paper} elevation={6} square>
                <div className={classes.paper}>
                    <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        {inputFields}
                        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                            <TextField />
                        }
                        {for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                            <TextField />
                        }}
                        <Button
                            type="submit"
                            fullWidth
                            variant="contained"
                            color="primary"
                            className={classes.submit}
                        >
                            Submit
                        </Button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    );
}
```

Here is the error I am getting: **SyntaxError: Unexpected token**.

[image]

[image]

I am still learning React, so I am pretty sure I am doing it wrong. How does one render multiple elements with a for loop? Is there a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: `for(){}` is JS code. To embed JS code in JSX, you must put it inside two curly braces such as: `{for (){}}`

Comment: Thanks, but I get the same error (Unexpected token), this time on the for. Updated the question description with this.

Comment: @AntoineWeber Just adding {} around the for loop wont work as the final content must be JSX.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out why the `for` loop does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put javascript code in JSX declaration. You must use {} to denote any javascript code that is used to generate JSX.

Using something like this instead of your for loop would work as long as you put it in curly brackets.

```
 new Array(5).fill().map(() => <TextField/>)
```

Final result :

```
function App() {
    ...

    return (
        <Grid container className={classes.root}>
            <CssBaseline />
            <Grid item xs={false} md={7} className={classes.image} />
            <Grid item xs={12} md={5} component={Paper} elevation={6} square>
                <div className={classes.paper}>
                    <form className={classes.form} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        {new Array(5).fill().map(() => <TextField/>)}
                        <Button
                            type="submit"
                            fullWidth
                            variant="contained"
                            color="primary"
                            className={classes.submit}
                        >
                            Submit
                        </Button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to understand why can't I use a regular for loop even with curly brackets?

Comment: @reddfox The curly brackets don't denote that you can write any javascript, but instead that you can use javascript functions to create JSX.

Comment: I think you forgot `fill()` in `Array(5).fill().map`

Answer (score 2):

We must embed some JS code that returns some JSX or an array of JSX.

```js
{new Array(5).fill().map((_) => (
      <TextField/>
      ))}
```

This code creates an array of 5 `undefined` elements. Then, `.map` returns an array with each `undefined` element transformed to `<TextField/>`.

Hence we return an array of JSX.

I believe the main reason it does not work is that the `for` loop does not return JSX.